# Keras cross entropy loss

Tags: keras

How can I compute cross-entropy in keras?
I compute L1 loss as follows:

```
def l1_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

from https://keras.io/backend/

```
K.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)
```

> **categorical_crossentropy**
>
> categorical_crossentropy(output, target, from_logits=False)
>
> Categorical crossentropy between an output tensor and a target tensor.
>
> Arguments:
>
> - output: A tensor resulting from a softmax (unless from_logits is True,
>     in which case output is expected to be the logits).
> - target: A tensor of the same shape as output.
> - from_logits: Boolean, whether output is
>     the result of a softmax, or is a tensor of logits.

Comment: What about the axis?

Comment: I looked at the code and it has no axis option. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/keras/backend.  It most likely assumes your data is categorical (one hot encoded matrix where each line is a sample with the one hot vector with zeros everywhere except in the correct class)